# Convert an Array of Ints Representing a Binary Number to a Decimal Number

Tags: arrays, c, binary, decimal

I have an array of ints that represent a binary number. I need to convert it to its decimal integer equivalent. Can someone please help me?

```
int octet[8] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0};
```

I want to return the decimal equivalent which would be **74** in this case.

Comment: How do you know it is 74? Maybe you can tell the computer how you have calculated it using C?

Comment: What algorithm did you use for solving this in your head? Have you tried using that algorithm also in C? If yes, then please show us what you have tried. You may want to read this for further information: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12149471)

Comment: Ah - each integer in the octet array represents a single binary digit.  And from your answer, I see that  octet[7] represents the least significant bit.  So therefore it is 64 + 8 + 2 == 74

Comment: `int i = octet[0]*128 + octet[1]*64 + octet[2]*32 + octet[3]*16 + octet[4]*8 + octet[5]*4 + octet[6]*2 + octet[7];`

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how you could do something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                      
                                                                            
int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
                                                                            
    int octet[] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0};                                    
    int *p = octet;                                                             
    int len = sizeof(octet) / sizeof(octet[0]); // 8                                                                
    unsigned result = 0;                                                        
                                                                                
    while(len--) result = (result<<1) | *p++;                                   
    /* 74 */                                                                     
    printf("%u\n", result);                                                     
                                                                                
}
```

Comment: this answer contains the 'magic' number 8.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest allowing the compiler do all the 'heavy lifting' by letting the compiler calculate number of elements in the array and using that compiler calculated number as the limit for the loop

Answer (score 1):

2^0 x the last element + 2^1 x the second-to-last element + 2^2 x the third-to-last element + ...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()                                                                      
{
  // Make array constant and let the compiler tell us how many elements are contained.
  // Doing it this way allows "octet" to grow up to the number of bits in an integer elements.  
  // It won't be an "octet" anymore though,...
  const int octet[] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0};         
  const int NumArrayElements = sizeof(octet) / sizeof(*octet);

  // Assign hi bit to save a loop iteration.
  int value = octet[0];
  
  // Run remaining bits, shifting up and or-ing in new values.
  for(int i=1; i<NumArrayElements; i++)
  {
    value <<= 1;
    value |= octet[i];
  }
  
  printf("%d\n", value);
}
```

This is a simple thing to do, but having the compiler handle some of the sizing issues and adding comments makes it much easier to maintain over time.